# How to filter Arraylist with RxJava2

Tags: java, android, arraylist, rx-java2

WAnt to filter list with `RxJava2`. somehow got it working. but the prob is, it is returning only *one* item in List in `Consumer` callback(size is always 1)

here is the code:

```
 Observable.fromIterable(arraylist)
                   .filter(new Predicate<BasicListModel>() {
                       @Override
                       public boolean test(BasicListModel model) throws Exception {
                           return true; //returning true for all items in filter
                       }
                   })
                   .toList()
                   .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                   .subscribe(new Consumer<List<BasicListModel>>() {
                       @Override
                       public void accept(List<BasicListModel> models) throws Exception {

                               Log.i("TAG"," size:"+models.size());

                       }
                   });
```

i am new to RxJAva1 or RxJava2.

Comment: How many `BasicListModel` items are in `offerBasicListModel`? What type does `offerBasicListModel` have, is it a queue of some sort?

Comment: dynamic size. can go above 16. tested with 15 size now. `offerBasicListModel` is just the arraylist name i forgot to change in question . dont get confused with two different name. editing now

Comment: `fromIterable` is essentially snapshot based. if you keep changing the arrayList, the flow won't know about it until the next time there is a subscription to the flow.

Comment: @akarnokd yes i am facing issue with Aks4125 code. every time i called filter function it returned me different sized list. is it the issue you referring to? i have implemented with this in different way. will post the answer here today

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can filter with proper iteration as followed

```
Observable.fromIterable(offerBasicListModel)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .filter(new Predicate<BasicListModel>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(BasicListModel model) throws Exception {

                    if (model.isDownloading()) //assume
                        return true; // if true, object will redirect to `doOnNext`
                    else
                        return false;
                }
            })
            .doOnNext(new Consumer<BasicListModel>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(BasicListModel model) throws Exception {
                    Log.d("objects one by one ->",model.getId());
                }
            })
            .toList()
            .subscribe(new Consumer<List<BasicListModel>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(List<BasicListModel> model) throws Exception {
                    Log.d(TAG, "filtered list size: "+model.size());
                }
            });
```

if you're supporting java 8, then

```
Observable.fromIterable(offerBasicListModel)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .filter(BasicListModel::isDownloading)
            .doOnNext(
            model ->Log.d(TAG,"filtered objects one by one ->",model.getId())
            )
            .toList()
            .subscribe(model -> Log.d(TAG, "filtered list size: "+model.size()));
```

**UPDATE**

> Custom User model

```
public class UserModel {

private int age;
private String name;

public UserModel(int age, String name) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
} 
}
```

> perform filtering user with age above 18

```
ArrayList<UserModel> userModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    UserModel user;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            user = new UserModel(25, "user" + i);
        else
            user = new UserModel(15, "user" + i);

        userModelArrayList.add(user);
    }

    io.reactivex.Observable
            .fromIterable(userModelArrayList)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .filter(userModel -> userModel.getAge() > 18)
            .toList()
            .subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<UserModel>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    /* to do */
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<UserModel> userModels) {
                    Log.d("userModels", " after filtering: " + userModels.size());

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    /* to do */
                }
            });
```

Here I am able to achieve 10 filtered user objects in `onSuccess()`.

I suggest you to try this approach first using sample code if it is working then you can modify and trace where exactly you're doing wrong.

[image: Result]

Comment: your solution worked. what did i miss in my code? `doOnNext`? does this increment internally in the list? help me to understand this.

Comment: `doOnNext` was missing in your code. it only consumes successful response. Besides, I wrote this code in rxjava2 and I am able to fetch correct filter size. You can also use `all(..)` or `concatMap(..)` if you still want to do operations on filtered list. make sure you call above methods below `filter(..)` only. Please accept if this worked for you for future stack users

Comment: As testing continued. this approach somehow was not returning me complete filtered data. missed many items from list. returned me different array sized list every time i used it. any idea why this was happening?

Comment: can you edit your question with sample model class and filter operation? That way i can explain better for your understanding.

Comment: can say i check `model.age>=18` a simple filter. it not complicated.

Comment: @JolsonDaCosta I have updated my answer. please check

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding `onCompleted` on your `Subscriber` to notify when the list has emitted all the values?

Answer (score 0):

as with Aks4125 solution i was able to filter List. but everytime i called Filter function it returned me different sized List.

modified my code with `Observer` callback. worked fine but had to write little extra code to make the list, as it was returning one `Object` at a time.

here is the code:

```
Observable.fromIterable(arraylist)
                    .filter(new Predicate<BasicListModel>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean test(BasicListModel model) throws Exception {
                             if(filter){
                                return true;
                                  }else{
                                return false;
                                  }
                    })
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<BasicListModel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable disposable) {
                            filteredBasicListModel.clear();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(BasicListModel basicListModel) {
                            filteredBasicListModel.add(basicListModel);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {
                            Log.i("TAG","size :"+filteredBasicListModel.size());
                    });
```

this is working solution to me currently. if it can be optimized any better. am open to solution.

Learning and Improving.

Comment: check **Update** in my answer

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `.blockingGet()` after your `toList()` call. This will remove all asynchronicity.

Comment: `.toBlocking().single()` both methods are not recognized

Comment: kind of beats the purpose of using RX

Comment: Oops, yeah those are RxJava1 methods. Try .blockingGet()

Comment: @TimCastelijns You're saying the only purpose of Rx is asynchronicity?